# MFMailComposeViewController produces empty lines in front of image attachments

Tags: iphone, outlook, email-attachments, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I use MFMailComposeViewController for creating eMails on iPhone. These mails includes text, a text-attachment and some image attachments.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailController setToRecipients:recipients];
    if ([ccRecipients count] > 0) [mailController setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
    [mailController setSubject:project];
    [mailController setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];

    if (csv) {
        [mailController addAttachmentData:csvData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:csvFileName]; 
    }

    QEMailAddPicturesOperation * operation = [[QEMailAddPicturesOperation alloc] init];
    operation.delegate = self;
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
}

@implementation QEMailAddPicturesOperation

- (void) main {
    ....
    for (NSString * fileName in listOfPictures) {
        NSString * path = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path], PIC_COMPRESSION_RATE );
        [mailController addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:fileName];
    }
}
```

All works fine, i can send the mail.
But the result is:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=Apple-Mail-256A861D-10BB-4031-8DFB-0E8FDA8F9337

....

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Mime-Version: 1.0 (1.0)
X-Mailer: iPhone Mail (9A405)

....

--Apple-Mail-256A861D-10BB-4031-8DFB-0E8FDA8F9337
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7BIT
Content-Type: TEXT/plain;
charset=us-ascii





--Apple-Mail-256A861D-10BB-4031-8DFB-0E8FDA8F9337
Content-Disposition: inline;
filename=MFA_001.JPG
Content-Type: IMAGE/jpg;

....
```

You see: the mail composer puts several text-lines between the attached (and base64-coded) images.

Outlook 2010 interprets these lines as an attachment (ATT......). For example sending 8 images creates 8 additional, but empty attachments in Outlook. Outlook also shows the signature of the iPhone-Mail as an attachment. Outlook 2011 on Mac works.

How can I avoid the creation of the empty lines on iPhone or the creation of the attachments in Outlook (2007, 2010)?

Answer (score 0):

I had reposted the question here - [MFMailComposeViewController Attaches Signature as .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043596/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-attaches-signature-as-txt-file) since there was no answer.

After some more digging, this is an issue with the exchange server and not with Swift/ iOS/ etc. It has to do with the way that Exchange expects email content to be ordered. I haven't found a clear answer on if the newer versions of Exchange address the issue. The MIT link specifically mentions Exchange Server 2007 & 2010. Also, I was able to confirm that the issue is when the mail is being sent by Exchange, not received.

http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4981187

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/969854/the-body-of-a-message-is-shown-incorrectly-as-an-attachment-if-you-try