# MFMailComposeViewController Attaches Signature as .txt file

Tags: ios, swift, email, exchange-server

I'm sending a pdf through MFMailComposeViewController. The sender's signature is seen as an attachment when viewed in Outlook, but not the iOS native mail app.Everything else works as expected.

What is the reason the signature is showing an attachment?

```
@IBAction func sendSpecSheetWithEmailButton(_ sender: subclassedUIButton) {
    buttonURL = sender.urlString!
    specName = sender.specSheetName!
    let fileURL = URL(string: buttonURL)
    if fileURL == URL(string: "https://www.example.com") {
        alertUserSpecNotAvailable(fileURL: fileURL!, specName: specName)
    } else {
        sendMail(fileURL: fileURL!, attachmentType: "pdf", to: [""], cc: ["team@example.com"], subject: "Spec Sheet", message: "The spec sheet you requested is attached. \n\nSent via Our iPhone app")
    }
}
```

Someone asked a similar question on here years ago, but there was never a clear answer.

Edit: here is sendMail()

```
func sendMail (fileURL: URL, attachmentType: String, to: [String]?, cc: [String], subject: String, message: String) {
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setSubject(subject)
        mail.setToRecipients(to)
        mail.setCcRecipients(cc)
        mail.setMessageBody(message, isHTML: false)

        switch attachmentType {
        case "pdf":
            if let fileData = NSData(contentsOf: fileURL as URL) {
                print("File data loaded.")
                mail.addAttachmentData( fileData as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: specName)
            }
            return self.present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case "url":
            mail.setMessageBody("The requested spec sheet is can be found here: \(fileURL)", isHTML: true)
            return self.present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case "none":
            return self.present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        default: break
        }
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be because `attachmentType: "pdf"` is wrong?

Comment: Added code to show where attachmentType is used. Also, the pdf is working just fine.

Comment: What is `specName`?

Comment: Also, I notice that your URL is wrong. You are failing to take a `fileURL`. You are calling your variable `fileURL` but your URL is _not_ a `fileURL`.

Comment: There's no point saying "the pdf is working just fine". The pdf is _not_ working fine. It may come through, but clearly something is going wrong with the mail multi-part mime attachment coding.

Comment: You can't even see fileURL...? How could you know that it's not a file? The only URL shown above is a check to see if the URL sent by the button is the default URL. The fileURL sent from the button is example.com/assests/images/equipmentspec/specName.pdf

Comment: specName is for UIAlert. It has nothing to do with the MFMailCompose.

Comment: Yes, the PDF does work just fine. The fileURL points to a file on our domain that is successfully attached to the email. So fileURL is definitely for a file.. which is sent as expected.

Comment: "specName is for UIAlert. It has nothing to do with the MFMailCompose", No, because you are passing it in to `mail.addAttachmentData`. — Look, if you want help, you really have to provide enough info that the problem can be reproduced. That means we need to know what your variable values are at the point you configure the MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: Okay so specName is a String coming from the button property. It does not include the file extension. I'll try downloading the file to temporary folder and try to work with that. It'll be later tonight before I can update. I'll post back with the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, this is an issue with the exchange server and not with Swift/ iOS/ etc. It has to do with the way that Exchange expects email content to be ordered. I haven't found a clear answer on if the newer versions of Exchange address the issue. The MIT link specifically mentions Exchange Server 2007 & 2010. Also, I was able to confirm that the issue is when the mail is being sent by Exchange, not received.

http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4981187

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/969854/the-body-of-a-message-is-shown-incorrectly-as-an-attachment-if-you-try